# Pandas series to 2d array

Tags: python, pandas

So, I used the answer from [Put a 2d Array into a Pandas Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840319/put-a-2d-array-into-a-pandas-series) to put 2D numpy array to pandas series.
In short, it is

```
a = np.zeros((5,2))
s = pd.Series(list(a))
```

Now, what is the cheapest way to convert that pandas Series back to 2D array?
If I try `s.values`, I get array of arrays with `object` dtype.

So far I tried `np.vstack(s.values)` but it copies the data, of course.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
a = np.array(s.values.tolist())
print (a)
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
```

---

```
a = np.zeros((50000,2))
s = pd.Series(list(a))

In [131]: %timeit (np.vstack(s.values))
10 loops, best of 3: 107 ms per loop

In [132]: %timeit (np.array(s.values.tolist()))
10 loops, best of 3: 19.7 ms per loop

In [133]: %timeit (np.array(s.tolist()))
100 loops, best of 3: 19.6 ms per loop
```

But if transpose difference is small (but [caching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29765693)):

```
a = np.zeros((2,50000))
s = pd.Series(list(a))
#print (s)

In [159]: %timeit (np.vstack(s.values))
The slowest run took 23.31 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 55.7 µs per loop

In [160]: %timeit (np.array(s.values.tolist()))
The slowest run took 7.20 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 49.8 µs per loop

In [161]: %timeit (np.array(s.tolist()))
The slowest run took 7.31 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 62.6 µs per loop
```