# Convert series to 2d array

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823400/pandas-series-to-2d-array) to convert a series into a 2d array but it doesn't work.

The dataframe

```
d = {'col1': [1,1,1], 'col2': [2,2,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

My code

`np.array(df['col1'].values.tolist())`

It returns a 1d array with shape`(3,)`

`array([1, 1, 1])`

I'm looking for array with shape `(3,1)`

Where should I revise my code ? thanks

Comment: `df.to_numpy()`? OR `df.T.to_numpy()`?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @PabloC I want the output array has shape (3,1)

Comment: instead of passing a series pass a dataframe, check my answer.

Comment: what if you reshape it? `df["col1"].to_numpy().reshape((3,1))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `df['col1']` is a series object
- `df[['col1']]` is a single column dataframe

When using `.to_numpy()`, passing a series object will return a 1D array. However, when passing a dataframe, it will return a 2D arrays where the column and row structure is retained (in this case a single column and 3 rows)

Try using this. -

```
df[['col1']].to_numpy()
```

```
array([[1],
       [1],
       [1]])

#shape = (3,1)
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with .to_numpy() as follow. For reference, you may visit [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': [1,1,1,], 'col2': [2,2,2,]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df.to_numpy())
```

Comment: hi I want to convert a series, df['col1'].to_numpt() still returns a 1d array